# How can I create a MySQL query within a query and concatenate?

Tags: mysql

So I have the following table, `users`:

```
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name      | varchar(60)      | NO   | UNI |         |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the table, `roles`:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(64)      | NO   | UNI |         |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have a third table, `users_roles`, which in a one-to-many relationship maps `users` to one or more `roles`:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| rid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Finally, I have a fourth table, `memberships`, that maps one-to-one with `users`:

```
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| membership_no     | varchar(32)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| uid               | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently I have a nice and simple query that provides a list of users with their membership number:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, m.membership_no FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN memberships AS m ON u.uid = m.uid;
```

But now I would like to add an additional column to my query that looks up all the `users_roles` entries once per user, and then concatenates each `roles.name` in one column, so I can see all the roles for that user. An example output might be:

```
uid    name       membership no    roles
---    ----       -----            ------
1      foo        123432           admin, normal user, student
2      bar baz    235235           admin
3      bak        2352352          normal user, student
```

So my task is how I would integrate this additional query on the `users_roles` table, link `user_roles.rid` to `roles.rid` and concatenate the data in a column. Any pointers?

Comment: You *can* use GROUP_CONCAT, although personally, I prefer to handle array manipulation at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function.

```
SELECT 
u.uid, 
u.name, 
m.membership_no,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM users_roles ur INNER JOIN roles r ON r.rid = ur.rid WHERE ur.uid = u.uid) as roles
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN memberships AS m ON u.uid = m.uid;
```

Comment: I'd probably prefer a JOIN over a subquery, but this is indeed one solution.

Comment: LOL just cause I said it I got picked. But, I still think it is :)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  First JOIN the other tables, so you can get the role names, then GROUP them together by user id.

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, m.membership_no, GROUP_CONCAT(r.name ORDER BY r.rid) AS roles
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN memberships AS m ON u.uid = m.uid
JOIN users_roles AS ur ON u.uid = ur.uid
JOIN roles AS r ON ur.rid = r.rid
GROUP BY u.uid
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffa31/1